# How to access textbox inside UserControl from another one

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

So I've `MainPage` Form and this form contains three UserControl `newIngredient`, `recipeAcrhive`, `recipesCenter`, I've tried to access visible property of `recipesCenter` from `recipeAcrhive` because I want to access textbox in recipesCenter then show `recipesCenter` the but this was useless and I've tried a lot of solutions like

**The confusion here is `recipeAcrhive` disappears and `recipesCenter` remain invisible**

### First Solution

create new instance from `MainPage` then access `recipesCenter` using Controls property and access textbox then hide `recipeAcrhive` and finally show `recipesCenter`

```cs
frmMainPage frm = new frmMainPage();
frm.Controls["recipesCenter"].Controls["txtName"].Text = "Meet";
this.Visible = false;
frm.Controls["recipesCenter"].Visible = true;
```

### Second Solution

create new instance from `MainPage` and `RecipesCenter` then access textbox using Controls property and hide `recipeAcrhive` finally add RecipesCenter's instance into `MainPage` Form controls

```cs
frmMainPage frm = new frmMainPage();
RecipesCenter rc = new RecipesCenter();
rc.Controls["recipesCenter"].Controls["txtName"].Text = "Meet";
frm.Controls.Add(rc);
```

### Third Solution

create method in `MainPage` and inside this method I make `recipeArchive` with hide visibility and `recipesCenter` with show visibility and access this method from recipeArchive using `MainPage` instance

```cs
// inside MainPage
public void showRecipesCenter() {
    recipeArchive.Visible = false;
    recipesCenter.Visible = true;
}

// inside recipeArchive
frmMainPage frm = new frmMainPage();
frm.showRecipesCenter();
```

Anyone can help me and make my day

Comment: You need to use an instance of the form and the form cannot close when you return so you have to capture the close event.  See my two form project :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: I see no reason why you would need a 2nd form; all you need to do is to change the __modifier__ (in the properties panel) of the TextBox in the Usercontrol from `private` to, say, `internal`.

Comment: @TaW I've try to change modifier but this was useless

Comment: _but this was useless_ This is not a helpful problem description! Not here nor in the post!! Having a non-private access modifier in necessary to access a control. But you also write about visibilty, which is a totally different thing. So you need to explain much better  what you want and happens and what goes wrong and which error messages you encounter, or else we can't help you! - Note that creating new instances of your form is a very common beginners' mistake. Do not do that!!

Comment: If you need one UserControl to communicate with another, I'd use the Form as the middle-man.  Make the first UserControl raise a CUSTOM EVENT that the Form subscribes to.  When the Form receives the event, it can pass on the message to the second UserControl.  This way the two UserControls don't need to know about each other directly.  The Form knows about both of them, so why not use that fact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution and, the code must be like so

```cs
public partial class frmMainPage : Form {
    public frmMainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static frmMainPage frm;

    public static frmMainPage Instance {
         get {
             if (frm == null)
                 frm = new frmMainPage();
             return frm;
         }
    }

    private void frmMainPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         frm = this;
    }
}
```

And inside your `UserControl` the code must be like so

```cs
public partial class yourUserControl : UserControl {      
    frmMainPage.Instance.anotherUserControl.txtName.Text = "Stack Overflow";
}
```

Comment: This works, but a better (more idiomatic) way is for the user control to raise an event, the main form handles that event and makes changes to other controls.  That way each user control doesn't have to know about the internal structure of other controls.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sure, you are right. This definition that you mean is called `Loosely Coupled`